# Get a particular text from website

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm looking for a way if you know the location where to read the text for example say, under a particular category, how would you connect to a website and search & read the text from it?
what steps do i need to follow to learn about that?

Comment: I'm not sure how to relate the tags you specified to the question you're asking...

Comment: So you want to download and parse HTML from C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use libcurl/cURL for your HTML retrival

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a [web crawler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler).

Here's an example of a [simple crawler written in C++](http://www.example-code.com/vcpp/spider_simpleCrawler.asp).

Moreover, you might want to have a look to [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), a software to retrieve files via HTTP, HTTPS and FTP.

Comment: That crawler is quite basic =D

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking at a specific web-page, you could try retrieving the page and parsing it to get to the exact location you want. e.g. specific div, etc.

since you are using c++, you could try reading up on using libcurl to retrieve the information you need from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an html file with [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384270(VS.85).aspx#Downloading_resource)(working example) and then search the file. There's some find algos in the std::string class for searching if your needs are relatively basic.